# Create model variable name and name in Spring Boot (Java) from js file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a backend for my frontend application that uses Spring Boot as a base.

I have a js `data.js` file with a structure similar to this:

```
export default [
    {
        "key": "send-template-and-sign",
        
        "form": ["firstName","lastName","email","startDate","includeServices"]
    },{
        "key": "upload-and-auto-send",
        
        "form": ["recipientOneFirstName","recipientOneLastName","recipientOneEmail","startDate","includeServices","recipientTwoFirstName","recipientTwoLastName","recipientTwoEmail","fileOneBase64","fileTwoBase64"]
    },

    {
        "key": "send-template-url",
        
        "form": ["OneFirstName","TwoFirstName","ThreeFirstName","OneLastName","TwoLastName","ThreeLastName"]
    }
]
```

Where the key variable is my class identifier and the form indicates the variables I want to create. All my forms are `String` tipe.
I want a generic code where I make a loop for all the objects and create the class depending on the key with their respective variables.

Something similar to this but generic for everything:

```
@Entity

//Create de name class from the key name
public class send-template-and-sign implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
//Create a loop from here
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String startDate;
    private String includeServices;
//To here
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
//Another Loop from here
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getIncludeServices() {
        return includeServices;
    }

    public void setIncludeServices(String includeServices) {
        this.includeServices = includeServices;
    }
//To here
}
```

With the same code create a second loop for n number of itiration like this:

```
@Entity
public class upload-and-auto-send implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String recipientOneFirstName;
    private String recipientOneLastName;
    private String recipientOneEmail;
    private String recipientTwoFirstName;
    private String recipientTwoLastName;
    private String recipientTwoEmail;
    private String fileOneBase64;
    private String fileTwoBase64;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRecipientOneFirstName() {
        return recipientOneFirstName;
    }

    public void setRecipientOneFirstName(String recipientOneFirstName) {
        this.recipientOneFirstName = recipientOneFirstName;
    }

    public String getRecipientOneLastName() {
        return recipientOneLastName;
    }

    public void setRecipientOneLastName(String recipientOneLastName) {
        this.recipientOneLastName = recipientOneLastName;
    }

    public String getRecipientOneEmail() {
        return recipientOneEmail;
    }

    public void setRecipientOneEmail(String recipientOneEmail) {
        this.recipientOneEmail = recipientOneEmail;
    }

    public String getRecipientTwoFirstName() {
        return recipientTwoFirstName;
    }

    public void setRecipientTwoFirstName(String recipientTwoFirstName) {
        this.recipientTwoFirstName = recipientTwoFirstName;
    }

    public String getRecipientTwoLastName() {
        return recipientTwoLastName;
    }

    public void setRecipientTwoLastName(String recipientTwoLastName) {
        this.recipientTwoLastName = recipientTwoLastName;
    }

    public String getRecipientTwoEmail() {
        return recipientTwoEmail;
    }

    public void setRecipientTwoEmail(String recipientTwoEmail) {
        this.recipientTwoEmail = recipientTwoEmail;
    }

    public String getFileOneBase64() {
        return fileOneBase64;
    }

    public void setFileOneBase64(String fileOneBase64) {
        this.fileOneBase64 = fileOneBase64;
    }

    public String getFileTwoBase64() {
        return fileTwoBase64;
    }

    public void setFileTwoBase64(String fileTwoBase64) {
        this.fileTwoBase64 = fileTwoBase64;
    }
}
```

All created with one code. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `HashMap` to make it dynamic.

This way:

```java
/*
* This works this way:
* 1) send-template-and-sign ->
*                               "firstName" -> "John"
*                               "lastName" -> "Doe"....
* 2) upload-and-auto-send ->
*                               "recipientOneFirstName" -> "John"
*                               "recipientOneLastName" -> "Doe"....
* */
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> vars = new HashMap<>();



vars.put("send-template-and-sign", new HashMap<>());
vars.get("send-template-and-sign").put("firstName", "John");
vars.get("send-template-and-sign").put("lastName", "Doe");
// and so on
```

This way you have the data all saved somewhere, now you have only to think of a way to persist them in the DB.